# Unable to display celery tasks in djcelery admin (mongodb back end)

Tags: django, mongodb, admin, celery

my environment is composed of django, celery and mongodb as a back end.

I managed to create a periodic tasks using djcelery admin interface and after starting celerybeat I can see it runs. This task is simple: it just makes an addition of 2 integers as proposed in celery tutorial.

I launch **celeryd** with the following command line

> python manage.py celeryd -E -l INFO --settings=settings

**celerybeat** with the following command line:

> python manage.py celerybeat --settings=settings

and finally **celerycam** to take snapshots of my tasks:

> python manage.py celerycam --settings=settings

When I try to display celery tasks in djcelery admin however I keep having the same error message, does anyone know how to fix it ?

[image: Error stack django admin]

Comment: I am using the following libraries: APScheduler==2.0.2
Django==1.3.1
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.1
celery==2.4.6
celery-with-mongodb==2.4.1
django-celery==2.4.2
django-mongodb-engine==0.4.0
django-picklefield==0.1.9
djangotoolbox==0.9.2
kombu==2.0.0
pymongo==2.1
python-dateutil==1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not support advanced date/time lookups like `__day`, `__year`, `__hour` etc, this is why the `date_hierarchy` thing crashes.

However, the error message is pretty useless. Please open a ticket at https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/ with a link to the full stacktrace (you can get that by clicking the "paste" button on the Django error page).

Possible workarounds:

1. Override the djcelery admin that causes the trouble, removing the `date_hierarchy` option
2. Use django-dbindexer to add support for these lookups by using denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084009/what-are-the-django-celery-djcelery-tables-for) it stated that you should set specific Scheduler for the djcelery, but though I have configured this, my admin tasks page is empty (no exception, but does not get populated).

I'm using mysql as a storage for tasks.

Comment: Yes, it does not work for me either. Despite setting the correct value for the **CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER**. I wonder if it is related to mongodb as a backend but not sure. By the way how did you manage to set mysql for the storage of your tasks ? Do you have several back ends ?

Comment: I'm using [djkombu](https://github.com/ask/django-kombu) for this, this way my data and celery tasks are stored in a single place.